# Ruby gem to extract form data from fillable PDF

Tags: ruby, pdf

We are encountering PDF files that are fillable PDF forms containing user-supplied data. We'd like to extract the data the the user filled into the form but don't know of any gems that exist with this capability. So, for example, there's a field in the PDF form for "First name" which the user has completed with "David" -- we want to get our hands on the data such as "First name=>David"

Looking at the properties of a sample file tells me:

- PDF Producer: Adobe LiveCycle Designer ES 8.2
- PDF Version: 1.7, Adobe Extension Level 3 (Acrobat 9.x)

Advice and thoughts appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I use `active_pdftk` to fill forms it does have the functionality to dump fields as well although I have not tried it you current have to install through the github like so `gem 'active_pdftk', git: "https://github.com/tcocca/active_pdftk.git"`

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks -- going with PDFtk on the command line is my fallback -- am hoping there's a 'native' way in Ruby to get at the data...

Comment: you can use this gem in ruby and then parse the output file and remove it. That would be my suggestion but if you find another way please let me know as I may need to implement this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `dump_data_fields` method has a very standardized structure this Method should work for you needs it will output an Array with each field being a hash object.

```
def parse_pdf_dump(file)
  file = open(file,&:read)
  fields = file.split("---").delete_if{|f| f.empty?}
  #Create an Array of the fields 
  fields.map do |field|
    #Create a have of attribute => value for each field attribute
    Hash[
       field.split("\n").map do |line|
            split_line = line.split(":")
            #grab the name of the attribute
            name = split_line.shift
            #grab the value of the attribute
            #join is used in the case that the data originally had a : in it
            val = split_line.join(":")
            unless f_name.nil?
             [name.downcase, val.strip]
            end
       end
    ]
  end
end
```

Call like below using active_pdftk

```
require 'active_pdftk'
output_path = '/data_fields.txt'
pdftk = ActivePdftk::Wrapper.new(:path => [YOUR PATH TO PDFTK BINARY OR EXE])
pdftk.dump_data_fields([YOUR PDF], :output => output_path)
fields_array = parse_pdf_dump(output_path)
%x( rm output_path)
```

So You will be dumping the data fields with pdftk parsing them into an array `fields_array` and then removing the text file.